# Using Data On A QuerySting MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a redirect to an action like so...

```
  Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Error/{0}/?message={1}", action, exception.Message));
```

How to I have exception.Message available to the Action method when I get redirected?

```
 public ActionResult MyAction()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an argument in your Action to receive the query string param.

```
return RedirectToAction("Your_Action_Name", new { msg = exception.Message});
```

Your action:

```
public ActionResult Your_Action_Name(string msg)
```

Comment: Thanks, Im new to mvc I didnt realize the ActionResult parameter had to be the same variable name as the queryString parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect you can only have query string parameters. So:

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Error/{0}/?message={1}", action, exception.Message));
```

and :

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string message)
{
    ...
}
```

This being said, using `Response.Redirect` in an ASP.NET MVC application and hardcoding an url just seems **very wrong**. Unfortunately you haven't provided any context on what you are trying to do so I am not sure I can offer you any better suggestion than: don't use `Response.Redirect` in an ASP.NET MVC application. Use URL helpers and action results like:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    ...
    return RedirectToAction(action, "error", new { message = ex.Message });
}
```

If you are trying to implement some Global error handler than you are probably using the Application_Error event (you should have mentioned this in your question by the way) then you could have something among the lines:

```
var routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values["controller"] = "error";
routeData.Values["action"] = action;
routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;
IController errorController = new ErrorController();
errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
```

etc, etc, etc...